# How do you airdrop ERC20 tokens to certain NFT holders from a smart contract?

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity, nft, erc20

How do you airdrop ERC20 tokens to certain holders of an NFT all from a smart contract, let's say out of the 10k holders I only want to airdrop to NFT's from 1 to 1k

I can't find answers anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You can't find answer anywhere because it's a custom logic. You have to implement this in your contract.

Tips:

1. Connect you ERC20 and NFT contract to you new contract
2. You can get the owner by using `ownerOf` function from NFT contract.
3. Send bulk ERC20 transfer [like here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51513/doing-a-bulk-transaction-with-my-erc20-token-how-to-do-it)

Comment: how would I go about connecting a ERC20 contract to a NFT contract?

Comment: https://solidity-by-example.org/defi/staking-rewards/. Find the `stakingToken` variable. it's connecting one ERC20